# Flutter Firebase Forgot password

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, forgot-password

I'm working on a project where I'm using the authentification of firebase to use the forgot password thing. However, I have a collection users that I use as well and need the password field to be updated in the collection as well.
Any solutions please ?  I can't seem to find a way to get password from authentification.

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** store the passwords of your users.

Comment: I need them for the login since my app needs to have both login using email/password and some code given by the institution/password I use it to verify that the user exists and his password is correct.

Comment: I agree with @b2m9 here and it smells like there may be a security issue here. Longer answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is (very intentionally) no way to get a user's password from Firebase, and wanting to do so typically indicates an anti-pattern in your implementation.

If you already verify the user's credentials elsewhere, you shouldn't use Firebase to do the same (but for example [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) based on the external credentials). If you use Firebase to verify the user's password, you shouldn't repeat that in your code (although you can for example [decode the user's ID token to determine their identity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens)).

Comment: I actually need two ways to authenticate a user they can enter an email/password where I used the firebase auth and another where they can enter a code/password that's why I saved the password in a document. And using the password reset method it updates the password in the auth only so when the user is logging in using the code it still has the old password. Thank you for your help I'm not sure if you get what I meant but it looks like I'll just drop the code thing and oblige the user to use one way only. I appreciate your help.